# Firebase restrict childs return by ref

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a data saved like this:

```
users : {
   '1' : {
      'name':'jack',
      'old':21,
      'paymentCard':{
        ....
      }
   }
}
```

When I fetch my user like this:

```
ref.child('users/1').once('value', snapshot => {
   console.log(snapshot.val()); 
});
```

The result contain the paymentCard.

Is there a way to restrict child returned ?

Comment: What does it mean a way to restrict?

Comment: I want to get only 'name' and 'old' in my result and not 'paymentCard'

Comment: As @Vivek says: there is no way to return partial nodes. In addition to his  answer, see my explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648669/firebase-how-to-structure-public-private-user-data/38649032#38649032

Answer (score 3):

That's not possible with your current data structure. As mentioned in Firebase docs: Best Practices for Data Structure @ https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure

> when you fetch data at a location in your database, you also retrieve
>   all of its child nodes. In addition, when you grant someone read or
>   write access at a node in your database, you also grant them access to
>   all data under that node. Therefore, in practice, it's best to keep
>   your data structure as flat as possible.

So you should ideally have your data structure like:

```
users : {
   '1' : {
      'name':'jack',
      'old':21,
   }
}
paymentCard: {
   '1' : { // user id
        ....
   }
}
```

That way when you fetch data at `users/1` you will only get `name` and `old` values and to fetch payment card details you will need to access `paymentCard/1`.