# Firebase Database rules ignore child rule

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am trying to add a simple rule to firebase database. the child node activities have proper access but the leads don't. if I sent the parent read true and then child rules are ignored. how can I set parent true to public but child restricted?

[image]

```
    {
  "rules": {
    "leads": {
      "$activity": {
        ".read": 
    "root.child('users_business_activities').
    child(auth.uid).hasChild(data.child('category').val())",
        ".write" : 
    "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('isAdmin').val() == true"
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == true",
        ".write": "auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    },
    "business_activities": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == true",
        ".write": "false"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the Firebase [Realtime Database permissions cascade downwards](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#read_and_write_rules_cascade). Once you give a user read permission on `/leads`, you can't take that permission away lower in the JSON tree.

This has a few consequences:

- Security rules cannot be used to filter data. This is known as [rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#rules_are_not_filters) in the Firebase documentation. I also recommend reading some of the many existing [questions on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase%5d%20rules%20are%20not%20filters).
- You will often need to create a lookup list of the activity IDs that a user has access to. Such a lookup list is often known as an "index" in Firebase terms. The documentation on [creating scalable data structures](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#fanout) has a good example of such a structure.
- If part of the data for an activity/lead needs to be publicly readable, and part needs to remain private, you'll want to split the public and private parts into separate top-level nodes. This splitting is known as [flattening you data structure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#flatten_data_structures) in the docs. I also gave an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648669/firebase-how-to-structure-public-private-user-data) to show how to  use this for user profile information.

Comment: How is it "flattening" to create separate top-level nodes ?  I am not taunting, mind you, I do have a hard time understanding the logic of database rules.