# Firebase database security for new users

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is there a way to check the values using rules that are initially set on user creation?

I have perused the firebase docs to no avail.

When the function `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is called,  I then create some values in the database, for example:

```
    "users": {
        "ht35resf435dwe3rfdw": {
            "is_premium": false,
            "display_name" "John",
            "last_login": 15353723826
        }
    }
```

The problem I am facing is: `is_premium: false` is part of the front end code and I am worried that a user could somehow change this to `is_premium: true`.

I can't figure out a way to check that it is initially set to false on creation.

P.s I could be going about this all wrong, I am a junior so I would appreciate any and all pointers.

Comment: Is this for Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore?

Comment: @DougStevenson database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To only allow a value to be set to `false`, you can use a validation rule:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        "is_premium": {
          ".validate": "newData.isBoolean() && newData.val() == false"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above will simply only allow `false` to be written by any client. When you're writing using an Admin SDK however, those writes bypass these security rules. So you can use the Admin SDK to mark premium users.

Comment: ah! Thank you. This is what I was not understanding. I assumed if I set it to false and made it always false I would not be able to edit it later.

Comment: The main problem is always who "I" is in this scenario. Who is trusted, and who isn't. It's very easy to only allow the initial value to be false, but if you allow the user to then go back and change it, you've gained nothing. I realize now btw that the user won't be able to write their user node once you've changed `is_premium` to `true`. If that is a use-case you want to support, you'll have to have separate top-level nodes for the data the user can modify, the and the data they can't. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/38648669

Answer (score 0):

I just started using Firebase so I cannot provide much information. If you want to start learning it there is a great [series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jUPIes_B8vRjn1_GaplOPQ) you can watch. Also, I would suggest using Cloud Firestore instead of the Realtime Database because the ladder is older and has fewer features. Changing the security rules on your database will let you fiddle with which users can edit data. What you need to do is make the premium default to false or even not exist in the database and then create a javascript function to create or change it to true in the database.

EDIT:

Ajith Naruto's would work but it would also disallow all writing to the database from the web app.

EDIT 2:

Frank van Puffelen's should work I would go off of his answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can just change the security rules as below so that the user won't be able to make changes.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "foo": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false
    }
  }
}
```