# Firebase database rules - Allow unauthenticated users only filtered queries

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I Have a Google Firestore realtime database, which contains a flag `isPublic`. If set to `true`, the child node `details` can be read by unauthenticated users. If set to `false`, the record can only be accessed by one (for now) authenticated & authorized user.

The authorized user is the only one with write permission.

Further, the child node `private` always only grants access to the one authorized user.

The solution I have looked into is based on query based rules  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#query-based_rules
Unfortunately, I am getting a `permission_denied` response, even as the authorized user.

Info aside: this is in a Vue JS project using the Firebase SDK.

Here is my database sample.

The first product should have read access to `details` for unauthenticated users, but not to `private`.

The second one should not be shown to unauthenticated users at all, by forcing them to run the query `dbRef.orderByChild('isPublic').equalTo(true)`

```
"products": {
  "-pushIdxyz1" : {
    "isPublic" : true,

    "private" : {
      "notes" : "lorem ipsum always private",
      "soldDate" : ""
    },

    "details" : {
      "imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.imagexyz",
      "keywords" : "this, that",
      "title" : "Public product title",
      "workCategory" : "hardware",
    },
  },
  "-pushIdxyz2" : {
    "isPublic" : false,

    "private" : {
      "notes" : "lorem ipsum always private",
      "soldDate" : ""
    },

    "details" : {
      "imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.imagexyz",
      "keywords" : "this, that",
      "title" : "Secret product title",
      "workCategory" : "hardware",
    },
  }
}
```

And my not-working rules

```
"rules": {
  "products": {
    "$product_id": {
      ".indexOn": "isPublic",
      ".read": "query.equalTo == true || auth.uid == '[admin user id]'"
      // alternative attempt
      // ".read": "(query.orderByChild == 'isPublic' && query.equalTo == true) || auth.uid == '[admin user id]'",
      ,
      ".write": "auth.uid == '[admin user id]'",

      "details": {
        ".read": true,
      },
      "private": {
        ".read": "auth.uid == '[admin user id]'",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This query, for unauthorized users, should give read access to the details child node:

```js
firebase.database().ref('products').orderByChild('isPublic').equalTo(true).once('value')
  .then(...)
```

This query, for the authorized user only, should give read access to all data

```js
firebase.database().ref('products').once('value')
  .then(...)
```

With the current setting I am getting "permission denied" for either query, logged in as the authorized user or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Franks answer pointed me into the right direction (thank you!), but I decided to post a more complete answer myself.

Here's the data structure. Note that I changed 'isPublic' to 'isPublished'.
'products' now contains two child nodes: 'private' and 'public'. Both use the same key.

```
// Firebase Data
"products": {
  "private" : {
    "-pushId_1" : {
      "notes" : "Private notes product 1",
      "soldDate" : ""
    },
    "-pushId_2" : {
      "notes" : "Private notes product 2",
      "soldDate" : ""
    }

  },
  "public" : {
    "-pushId_1" : {
      "imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.imagexyz",
      "isPublished" : true,
      "title" : "Published product title",
    },
    "-pushId_2" : {
      "imageURL" : "https://firebasestorage.imagexyz",
      "isPublished" : false,
      "title" : "Unpublished product title, only accessible if authorized",
    }
  }
}
```

The rules allow admin everything and allow unauthenticated access to the public child node if the query looks for published products

```
// Firebase Rules
{
  "rules": {
    "products" : {
      ".read": "auth.uid == '[admin user id]'",
      ".write": "auth.uid == '[admin user id]'",

      "public" : {
        ".indexOn": "isPublished",
        ".read": "(query.orderByChild == 'isPublished' && query.equalTo == true)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To create new products, I am first pushing to 'public', then use the returned key to create the private record

```js
// Add new product
db.ref('products/public').push(publicData)
  .then((data) => {
    key = data.key
    return key
  })
  .then((key) => {
    db.ref('products/private').child(key).update(privateData)
    return key
  })
  .then( ... )
```

To get the products, public/unauthenticated users have to look for `isPublished` in public.
The admin can loop through public and private child nodes

```js
// Retrieve products - Public
db.ref('products/public').orderByChild('isPublished').equalTo(true).once('value')
  .then((data) => {
    let publicData = data.val()

    // Do something with the data
  })

// Retrieve products - Admin
db.ref('products').once('value')
  .then((data) => {
    let publicData = data.child('public').val()
    let privateData = data.child('private').val()

    // Do something with the data
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a user to be able to read from the `products` node, you will need to have a `.read` rule on that node. And since you only want to allow the read if it's a query for public products, you should validate that specific query.

Something like this:

```js
"rules": {
  "products": {
    ".indexOn": "isPublic",
    ".read": "(query.orderBy == 'isPublic' && query.equalTo == true)
              || auth.uid == '[admin user id]'"
  }
}
```

So:

1. You defined the rule one level too low, which means all reads on `/products` were rejected.
2. Your rule wasn't checking the `orderBy` field.

Note that the additional `.read` rule you've declared on `private` is meaningless here, since the same user already got read permission on the entire `products node anyway.

Comment: Thanks Frank. Two things though: 1. Your notes are right, but the code sample not. I could get it to work by moving the read rule under 'products'. But... 2. Now, if isPublic is true, the 'private' node can also be read by unauthorized users. So I guess that I have to move 'isPrivate' into it's own group. Let's say `products: { meta: {isPublic: true}, private: {...} }`. But I am now kind of lost how to set the rule for that

Comment: I just updated my answer to remove the extra level. Sorry about the copy/paste mistake.

Comment: Once a user has access to a node, they have access to all data under that node. There is no way to hide the private data from a node that they can read. You'll want to store the private data in a separate top-level node, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648669/firebase-how-to-structure-public-private-user-data