# Firestore database structure - Users and Profiles

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, database-design, nosql

Relatively new to NoSQL databases and am curious on what the best practice is for the following. I've also been reading https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data.

I have two types of users - let's say `Teachers` and `Students`. Each teacher and student has some private and public data.

Both the `Teachers` and `Students` public data are available for all to read.

The private data for `Students` is only available to read if the teacher's are subscribed (other students, non signed in users, and teachers unsubscribed are not eligible to see student's private data).

The private data for `Teachers` is eligible to be read if a user is logged in as a Teacher/Student.

**Database Structure**

I think the best way to go about this is the following :

Teach User Collection and Student User Collection - used solely for accessing the currently logged in user's information. This is not to be displayed to anyone but that individual.

2 collections:

```
Read and Write Privileges - isAuthorized() and isCurrentUser()

teacherUser : {
   {uid} : {
         name: "John Smith",
         email: "smith@gmail.com"
         role: "Teacher!" 
   }
}

studentUser: {
   {uid} : {
         name: "Jimmy",
         email: "jimmy@gmail.com"
         role: "Student!"
         differentFieldsBecauseImStudent: "BLAH"
   }
}
```

Public and Private Profiles for Teacher/Student - 4 collections

```
Read Privileges for Public Data - Everyone 
Write Privileges for Public and Private Data - isAuthorized() and isCurrentUser()
Read Privileges for Student Private Data - teacherIsSubscribed()
Read Privileges for Teacher Private Data - isAuthorized() 

teacherUserPublicProfile : {
  {uid} : {
        name: "John Smith",
  }
}
teacherUserPrivateProfile : {
  {uid} : {
        email: "smith@gmail.com"
  }
}

studentUserPublicProfile : {
  {uid} : {
        name: "Jimmy"
  }
}
studentUserPrivateProfile : {
    {uid} : {
        email: "jimmy@gmail.com"
        role: "Student!"
        differentFieldsBecauseImStudent: "BLAH"
    }
}
```

The benefit of this is it would make querying the data for public profiles very simple as well as maintaining the distinction between the types of users (who have different data and different business logic surrounding them). The downside is that it would require 3 separate writes on updating a profile (respective user, publicProfile, privateProfile) and have a lot of duplicate data. However, from what I've gathered - this is expected of NoSQL databases.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648669/firebase-how-to-structure-public-private-user-data, but a little bit more of a complex use case.

Comment: Duplicating data to meet the use-cases of your app is indeed expected when modeling NoSQL data. If your proposed data model works for the use-cases of your app and within any other constrains you've defined, it is the correct data model for you. If it doesn't meet those use-cases or violates those constraints, can you edit your question to clarify the specific use-case/contains?

Comment: If you're new to NoSQL databases and want to get to grips with them, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and then watching the [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video) series.

Comment: What is the question? PS [Why is asking a question on "best practice" a bad thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/142353/266284) 
[Strategy for “Which is better” questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) [ask] [Help]

Comment: Is there something wrong with your approach?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Those are pretty much all the use cases.

Comment: @philipxy The question is if there is an alternative approach to this, as there is a significant amount of redundancy. If the question is not appropriate or violates the rules, please feel free to close it if you have that ability.

Comment: @AlexMamo No, not necessarily. I'm curious if there is an alternative approach that folks would suggest that would be more efficient given the use cases.

Comment: Based on the responses - it seems that it's a perfectly acceptable structure given the use cases.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. [ask] [Help] [meta] [meta.se]